# How to create google form by Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-form-quiz

I want to make google form quiz by importing spreadsheets using google apps script.
I want to replace 'Cell A2' -> spreadsheet's A2 and 'Cell B2 -> spreadseet's B2. 
please help me.

```
var item25 = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
item25.setTitle('Cell A2')
item25.setChoices([
    item25.createChoice('Cell B2'),
    item25.createChoice('Cell B2')
 ])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting values from cells in google scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515670/getting-values-from-cells-in-google-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

### To access the values inside of ranges (cells) you need to retrieve

- the [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) of interest
- the [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) of interest
- the [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation) of interest
- the [value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) of this range

Sample:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("paste here the id").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var value1 = sheetgetRange("A1").getValue();
var value2 = sheetgetRange("B2").getValue();
var item25 = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
item25.setTitle(value1)
item25.setChoices([
    item25.createChoice(value2),
    item25.createChoice(value2)
 ])
```